# Is a "Fact" any theory for which there is overwhelming evidence in any field other than biology?

Tags: evolution, terminology, philosophy-of-science

Evolution is often described as a fact, and a theory. Evolution is a heavily overloaded term, with one definition being the fact that, "changes in the frequency of alleles in populations of organisms from generation to generation." This is a measurable fact, but not the usage of the word evolution that I am in interested in.

Wikipedia has several quotes on the matter, including the Webaters definition used in this questions title, but also includes clearly observational facts like the Earth revolves around the sun.

> A fact is a hypothesis that is so firmly supported by evidence that we assume it is true, and act as if it were true. —*Douglas Futuyma*
>
> There is no sharp line between speculation, hypothesis, theory, principle, and fact, but only a difference along a sliding scale, in the degree of probability of the idea. When we say a thing is a fact, then, we only mean that its probability is an extremely high one: so high that we are not bothered by doubt about it and are ready to act accordingly. Now in this use of the term fact, the only proper one, evolution is a fact. —*H. J. Muller*
>
> Scientists most often use the word "fact" to describe an observation. But scientists can also use fact to mean something that has been tested or observed so many times that there is no longer a compelling reason to keep testing or looking for examples. The occurrence of evolution in this sense is fact. Scientists no longer question whether descent with modification occurred because the evidence is so strong. —*National Academy of Science*

Do scientists refer to any theories for which there is overwhelming evidence as a "scientific fact", other than in biological sciences?

Note: Good answers will include quotes from scientific organizations or prominent scientists using the term **fact** to describe the theory, and will include references to the theory itself.

Comment: the definition of observation and fact (which is not often used in scientific discussions in my experience) are messier than you might think.  scientific proof is a messy business and different fields have different levels of evidence for publication, but they also have varying levels of application.  There is in practice no standard definition of these words in 'science' or 'biology' that I have seen, certainly none is taught in graduate school.

Comment: The use of the term "Law" (e.g., Newton's Laws of Motion, the Laws of Thermodynamics) seems comparable to the use of the term "fact".

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton, indeed. "Law" is an appropriate term, and is used often in Physics. I am interested in the supposed misuse of the term "fact" that scientists supposedly use according to the NAoS and others in fields other than biology. (Bonus points for not using climate scientists "fact" of the majority of warming is human caused in reference to the AGW theory.)

Comment: user1873-> Isn't the point of @PaulA.Clayton that the use of 'Law' in physics is an example from a field other than biology of a similar expression to denote a theory (in that both 'law' and 'fact' indicate a high degree of 'truth'). If you accept that 'scientific law' == 'scientific fact' then you have at least one example.

Comment: @fileunderwater, I don't accept scientific law == sci fact. The whole point of the question is that "fact" is supposedly used to indicate a high decree of certainty, and is used by scientists in this way. I cannot find any examples other than the very popular, "evolution is a fact." (And perhaps the AGW is a fact, but I am not sure if the source was a climate scientist). I doubt the claim that "fact" is used by scientists in this way.

Comment: @user1873 Is your disagreement only semantic? Or do you specifically have a problem with labelling 'evolution' or 'AGW' as law/fact? Your question seems to imply that you are asking for examples of other scientific fields where scientists are using a (casual) wording that implies that a theory is 'absolute truth'. If so, I think that the example from physics is valid. If you have a problem specifically with evolution (as a scientific theory or as as a theory deemed as'true' by most working scientists), that is a completely different question.

Comment: @fileunderwater, I suppose in a sense it is "only" [semantic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/dict.aspx?rd=1&word=semantic), since that is the root of the claim. I don't have any issue with the entomology of the word "fact" taking on this new meaning of  "any theory for which there is overwhelming evidence," my issue is with the claim that it has taken on that meaning when it appears that it only has in one specific case.  For example, If I claimed that the most women support abortion outside the womb, but insist that "abortion" meant, "to bottle feed an infant," some would take issue.

Comment: AFAIK, there are (1) evolution, (2) the Theory of Evolution and (3) Darwin's Theory of Evolution. (Other 'theories of evolution' could be counted.) The three are not equivalent. It seems that that you are asking about one of the three, but it's not clear which one.

Answer (score 3):

Your question really applies to any scientific theory, not just evolution.

The problem is that, outside of the scientific world, a theory is often thought as something unproven, an unproven guess if you wish. This is not true for scientific theories, which, instead are confirmed by experimental data.

The OED defines **theory** as:

> A scheme or system of ideas or statements held as an explanation or account of a group of facts or phenomena; a hypothesis that has been confirmed or established by observation or experiment, and is propounded or accepted as accounting for the known facts; a statement of what are held to be the general laws, principles, or causes of something known or observed.

and **fact** as:

> Something that has really occurred or is actually the case; something certainly known to be of this character; hence, a particular truth known by actual observation or authentic testimony, as opposed to what is merely inferred, or to a conjecture or fiction; a datum of experience, as distinguished from the conclusions that may be based upon it.

So, essentially we start with an unproven idea, we corroborate it with facts (=experimental data) and we define our theory accordingly to facts.

So, why don't we say that evolution is true or that it is a dogma or that it is a fact?

Well, that is not how science work. Evolution is a scientific theory, and it always will be. Maybe (hopefully, dare I say) in 50 years from now new evidence will have make us change the theory of evolution, at least some bits of it.
Luckily evolutionary biology is not stuck at the time of Darwin and genetics is not stuck at the time of Mendel. Many new pieces of evidence have made us **improve** the theories that they initially defined.

Does that mean they were bad scientist or that they experiments were faked? Not at all!  Simply as their knowledge was more restricted than ours, they could not formulate a more advanced theory. Mendel's experiments still hold true, but now we know that transmissions of characters is not as simple. He was just looking at *a special case*. And his experiments still fit in our current theory, and will have to fit in any future one.

A scientific theory is defined by its falsifiability, that is

> the trait of a statement, hypothesis, or theory whereby it could be shown to be false if some conceivable observation were true. In this sense, falsify is synonymous with nullify, meaning not "to commit fraud" but "show to be false".

The famous black swan example by Karl Popper (see e.g. [*Conjectures and refutations*, 1963, chapter 11.6](http://books.google.no/books?id=IENmxiVBaSoC&lpg=PP1&dq=Conjectures%20and%20Refutations%3A%20The%20Growth%20of%20Scientific%20Knowledge&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=Conjectures%20and%20Refutations%3a%20The%20Growth%20of%20Scientific%20Knowledge&f=false)), can be exemplified by (source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability)):

> One notices a white swan. From this one can conclude:
>       At least one swan is white.
>   From this, one may wish to conjecture:
>       All swans are white.
>   It is impractical to observe all the swans in the world to verify that they are all white.
>
> Even so, the statement all swans are white is testable by being falsifiable. For, if in testing many swans, the researcher finds a single black swan, then the statement all swans are white would be falsified by the counterexample of the single black swan.

So, our theory of the white swan is accepted as "temporary true", as long as a black swan is not found. Obviously the more white swans we count (i.e. the more experimental evidence we have), the stronger our theory will be. But it will never be true.

I would like to finish quoting Richard Feynman:

> It is scientific only to say what is more likely and what less likely, and not to be proving all the time the possible and impossible.

and

> We never are right, we can only be sure we're wrong

I suggest to watch the full video of his fantastic lecture on scientific method [on YouTube](http://youtu.be/EYPapE-3FRw).

Comment: An biologist, a physicist and a mathematician are on a train in Scotland. The biologist looks out of the window, sees a black sheep standing in a field, and remarks, "all sheep evolved in Scotland to be black because selective forces killed off the white sheep." "No, no, no!" says the physicist. "Only some Scottish sheep are black." The mathematician rolls his eyes at his companions' muddled thinking and says, "In Scotland, there is at least one sheep, at least one side of which appears to be black from here some of the time."

Comment: @user1873: you seem to have misread my answer. I never said scientists use fact in reference to theories. I am saying that a scientific theory, or a scientific model, is based on facts, that is experimental proofs. One, however, can never be certain a theory it is true (instead one can be certain a fact is true). So, if a scientist or a journalist or anyone else uses "theory" and "fact" interchangeably... well, they are doing it in an incorrect way as the two terms do not mean the same thing.

Comment: @user1873: the example of the sheep you make is a very good example of how a theory is just an interpretation of facts. The experimental evidence (the black sheep in the field) can be interpreted in (at least) three ways. All of those three are equally good scientific theories, as they are all falsifiable. You just need to go and look at the sheep from the other side of the field, or look at sheep in another country etc etc and some (or all) of those theories will be falsified. [cont'd]

Comment: [cont'd]You can then formulate a fourth theory, which is still consistent with that data but that takes into account the new data. All of the four theories are based on facts, but they are not facts, they are interpretations of the facts.

Comment: I just reread your 2nd comment. It seems you are saying that the NAoS is indeed full of it. It is unfortunate that Wikipedia keeps such misinformation on its pages for so long.

Comment: I am indeed disagreeing with what the NAoS says (just my opinion...). I don't doubt that sometimes if a theory is proven over and over again we take the "shortcut" of calling it a fact, but I am saying this is not really correct. I agree much more with the first quote when it says: "we act **as if** it were true". It is a shortcut, and I understand that sometimes it is handy to say "evolution is a fact" to respond to creationists arguing that "evolution is just a theory". But really, the way one should respond to that is "evolution is a theory, proven over and over again".

Comment: A direct quote to Popper on black swans could be: `That this minimum requirement cannot be satisfied ... may be shown with the help of Carnap's example, the law 'all swans are white'. This law ought to be considered *falsified* if our evidence consists of a flock of *one* black and, say, 1000 white swans. But upon this evidence, the instance confirmation, instead of being zero, will be very near to 1.`. This is from chapter 11.6 in *Conjectures and refutations*. I have added a reference in our answer to this passage, but as a stand-alone explanation the Wikipedia quote is better.

Comment: @nico In your answer and comments you write that a theory is an interpretation of facts, and that `one can be certain a fact is true`. This is however (as you probably know) a very simplified view. More modern descriptions of the scientific method all highlight how observations cannot be simply decoupled from theory (see e.g. Lakatos in *Criticism and the Growth of Knowledge* and Kuhn's *The Structure of Scientific Revolutions*, or, in more extreme form, Feyerabend's *Against method*). Therefore, you can just as well argue that observations and "facts" are theory dependent.

Comment: @fileunderwater: Thanks for the ref. Obviously theory and observation are not independent, but whereas theory can be viewed as an interpretation of observation, the other way around seems less likely. I can have my theory that cells are triangular, and it may be as nice a theory as I wish, but that will not have the effect of making cells triangular... :)

Comment: @nico Well, neither observations nor theories will change the physical reality, so no difference there. While I agree in practice that observations and theory have a different standing, with observations being closer to "actual facts", I still think that the point of theory-dependent observations cannot be so easily written off. A classical example would be astronomy, where raw 'observations' can consist of photon recordings from a distant star. For this raw 'observation' to be made into an *observation* (fact?) that has bearing on a particular hypothesis (e.g. dealing with ...

Comment: contd: ... the composition of the star) an entire body of work must be assumed. Auxilary theories and methods that has to be assumed true could include recording equipment, diffraction of light in the atmosphere and in space, how electromagnetic radiation is emitted etc. The point being that these observations don't exist except in relation to a complex network of theories. The astronomy example might be seen as extreme, but I can easily envision many similar situations in biology. But I probably digress from the main topic....

Comment: @fileunderwater: surely, I agree with you on that, but that is mostly because, for practical reasons, you cannot expect everyone to repeat every single experiment needed to justify his/her theory. A scientific experiment, however, should be repeatable, so in theory all those auxiliary theories could be reconfirmed (and if they are assumed as correct by the scientific community they probably have been reconfirmed over and over again). Still, that does not make them TRUE, just not false in accordance to what we know.

Comment: @user1873 I know this is old, but I had to steal that first comment. :D